Spring Jpa Jinq with Kotlin
I faced problem like this: In Spring Boot Kotlin project with JPA, I want to use Jinq. Referring to Baeldung I tried to write configuration and other class like following:
@Configuration
class JinqProviderConfiguration {
    @Bean
    @Autowired
    fun jinqProvider(emf: EntityManagerFactory): JinqJPAStreamProvider {
        return JinqJPAStreamProvider(emf)
    }
}

interface MyBasicRepository {
    fun getResponse(): List<BasicEntity>
}

abstract class BaseJinqRepositoryImpl<T>(
    private val jinqDataProvider: JinqJPAStreamProvider,
    @PersistenceContext private val entityManager: EntityManager
) {
    protected abstract fun entityType(): Class<T>

    fun stream(): JPAJinqStream<T> {
        return streamOf(entityType())
    }

    private fun <U> streamOf(clazz: Class<U>?): JPAJinqStream<U> {
        return jinqDataProvider.streamAll(entityManager, clazz)
    }
}

@Repository
class BasicRepositoryImpl(
    jinqDataProvider: JinqJPAStreamProvider,
    entityManager: EntityManager
) : BaseJinqRepositoryImpl<BasicEntity>(jinqDataProvider, entityManager), MyBasicRepository {

    override fun getResponse(): List<BasicEntity> {

        return stream().where {d -> d.currency == "USD"}.toList()

    }

    override fun entityType(): Class<BasicEntity> {
        return BasicEntity::class.java
    }
}

But in stream().where method compiler shows me error: Not enough information to infer type variable E
How can I solve it? Thanks in advance
UPDATED
After k314159 great help, I could run my project. But at the end it turned out that Kotlin lambda expression doesn't work with Jinq. It is pitty that I can't use Kotlin and Jinq together
stream().where(JinqStream.Where {d -> d.currency == "USD"}).toList()

Looking at the source, I would imagine the following would work: return stream().where<BasicEntity, Exception> {d -> d.currency == "USD"}.toList(). But I'm not sure why it works without explicit type parameters in Java but not in Kotlin. There must be an easier way to do this.

After these changes compiler show new error above d variable: Cannot infer a type for this parameter. Please specify it explicitly.

Try { d: BasicEntity -> d.currency == "USD" }

Thanks it solve error with d type. But there is another error again about where method:
None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied.
where(JinqStream.Where<DepositEntity!, TypeVariable(E)!>!)   where E = TypeVariable(E) for    fun <E : Exception!> where(p0: JinqStream.Where<DepositEntity!, E!>!): JPAJinqStream<DepositEntity!>! defined in org.jinq.jpa.JPAJinqStream

where(JinqStream.WhereWithSource<DepositEntity!, TypeVariable(E)!>!)   where E = TypeVariable(E) for    fun <E : Exception!> where(p0: JinqStream.WhereWithSource<DepositEntity!, E!>!): JPAJinqStream<DepositEntity!>! defined in org.jinq.jpa.JPAJinqStream

Try stream().where(Where<BasicEntity, Exception> {d -> d.currency == "USD"}).toList()

I can run project, but when I send request now this error was thrown
Unknown static method kotlin/jvm/internal/Intrinsics:areEqual(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Z encountered

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
